# Apscheduler: what is wrong with my configuration?

Tags: python-3.x, apscheduler

I have a stupid problem using apscheduler package for Python 3.
Seems to be very simple to set a periodic interval to run a simple function but I see a lot of "errors" related to the execution of the job. They are difficult to explain

This is my code:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

def timeJob():
    print("some job done")


def main():
    timeJob()
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(timeJob, 'interval', minutes=5)
    scheduler.start()
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

as you see the interval should be set to 5 minutes but in reality I see these errors:

```
code reload: Unable to find module to reload: sendIP
Execution of job "timeJob (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2022-10-26 03:22:04 CEST)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)
Execution of job "timeJob (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2022-10-26 03:23:04 CEST)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)
Execution of job "timeJob (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2022-10-26 03:24:04 CEST)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)
code reload: Unable to find module to reload: sendIP
Execution of job "timeJob (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2022-10-26 03:25:04 CEST)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)
```

and looking at it seems that the interval expires after 1 min, not after 5 as I set.
Do I have misunderstood something?

Comment: Could you provide a self contained example that others could run to reproduce the problem you're seeing?

Comment: I updated my initial post

Comment: Aside from the code never being actually run in the updated example, can you say that the example demonstrates the problem on your machine?

Comment: Yes, the code runs and produces the output I reported.

Comment: That's completely impossible because there is nothing that even calls the `main()` method.

Comment: Of course there is the call to main, it is not shown in my post because it is not relevant.

Comment: That just makes me wonder what else you've left out. Like what's printing those "code reload" lines? Certainly not apscheduler. If you're so confident about knowing what's relevant, why can't you figure this out on your own? If I just add a `main()` call to your snippet, it works just fine here.